# Kiel mi povas traduki "issue"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Saluton!

Kiel mi povas traduki la "GitHub issue"? Aŭ mi devas diri ĝin en la angla, "issue"? Kio estas plej bona?

Dankon!

Comment: `issue` literally could translate to `temo`. However the answer `raporto` is much more to the point here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofte oni trovas la vorton `problemo` (ne nur en la esperanta) [kiel tradukon](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=devtools/client/accessibility.properties:accessibility.filter.all2&repo=gecko_strings).

Sed kelkfoje ne temas pri problemo, sed pri deziro, sugesto, atentigo,... Tial vi ankaŭ povos vidi `atentindaĵo` aŭ `koncernaĵo`.

Konsiderinda estas ankaŭ `zorgo` ([en PIV](https://vortaro.net/#zorgo_kd): *Atenta penado certigi ies bonon...*) ĉar kutime issues estas kreitaj kun la celo plibonigi (ĉu ili raportas problemon, ĉu ili sugestas pli bonan manieron ion solvi, ekzemple).

Laste, en ĉiuj okazoj temas pri ia raporto:

> [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#raporto_kdc): Priskribo farita aŭ opinio formulita post esploro k
> konsidero pri difinita demando, kazo, teorio ks.

La radiko`raport-` cetere adapteblas facile al novaj, rilataj konceptojn kiel `erarraporto`, `dezirraporto`, `raportinto`, `misraporto`, ktp.

Mi do sugestus:

```
`Raportoj en Github`
```

aŭ unu el la supraj solvoj, kiujn vi povas ankaŭ kunmeti kun `raport-`, kiel ekzemple `problemraporto`.

Comment: Jes, en la angla la vorto "issue" ofte estas uzata eŭfenisme anstataŭ rekte diri "problem". Oni povas ankaŭ pensi, ke la unuopa afero, kiun oni atentu, nomiĝas "atentidaĵo" aparte tiam, kiam temas pri alia ol teknika problemo (ideo por plibonigo ktp.).

Comment: Koran dankon!! Ĝi estis problemo por mi ĉar GitHub ne estas tradukita, ĉar ne estas vere vorto por GitHub Issue. Sed Raporto en GitHub estas multe komprenebla kaj klara.

Comment: Bona mallongigo de prikomputila terminokolekto estas https://komputeko.net/

Answer (score 3):

Leginda estas la artikolo 'issue' en
https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto_i

Comment: Tiu listo, kiun Mike referencis, havas vorton "traktendaĵo", de [trakti](https://vortaro.net/#trakti_kd) + -end/ + aĵo, kiu ankaŭ sonas bona por unuopa afero.

Comment: En respondon bonvolu meti pli ol nur ligilon.

Answer (score 0):

Problemaĵo : aparta afero aŭ temo kiu plimalpli daŭre problemas.

Prizorgaĵo : aparta afero aŭ temo kiu postulas prizorgadon.

Solvendaĵo : aparta afero aŭ temo kiu ankoraŭ ne havas simplan solvon.